# How to generate data access layer with the help of dataset

Tags: c#, dataset, data-access-layer, strongly-typed-dataset

i hard that with the help of typed dataset data access layer can be generated. how to generate such data access layer from where we can do the operation like add/edit/delete/search data from store procedure and also send parameter. if anyone knows then please discuss in detail. thanks

Comment: be careful who you listen to. Typed datasets are old technology. You'd be far better off using Entity Framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save yourself some time and frustration.  Use the [ADO.NET Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for your data access.  It is the direction Microsoft is going and it is much easier to use and flexible than Typed DataSets.  I've used both and can say that once moving beyond typed DataSets I've never looked back.

Answer (score 1):

The very [first tutorial](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/creating-a-data-access-layer-cs) in the lenghy series [ASP.NET Data Access Tutorials](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials) will tell you how to do exactly that, using strongly-typed DataSets. That series contains details for building an extensive variety of web pages with various editable grids and master-detail pages using ASP.Net 2.0 technology and controls.

Details of creating editable web pages begin [here](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/an-overview-of-inserting-updating-and-deleting-data-cs).